# GCC creating dependencies for generated header files in proper directory

Tags: gcc, gnu-make

I use GCC to create dependency files, from header files stored in a
certain directory. Here is my recipe:

```
gcc -MM -MG -MT obj/$*.o -MP -MF dep/$*.Td -I include $<
```

One of these header files is generated (with Bison 3.0.5), so it may not
exist. I therefore use the -MG option as shown above, but it generates
a dependency without the directory. How can I tweak make or GCC to
prepend the include directory to the generated header?

Thanks in advance

dordow

Comment: Do you want the generated dependency to have an `include/` prefix?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the search path has many entries, and if the header file does not exist, it is unclear which prefix to pick.

The `cook` build tool comes with a program, `c_incl`, which scans C source files for `#include` directives and can be made to behave in the way you intend, with a command like `c_incl -No_Cache -Absent_System_Mention -Iinclude -C`.  But this tool is fairly obscure.

It is probably better to use a slightly less obscure GNU make feature instead: order-only prerequisites, as described in [Types of Prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html).  You would list the generated header files (or other Bison output files) as order-only prerequisites for all rules that compile C files, so that they are generated early on first build, but do not needlessly trigger rebuilds afterwards.  With this approach, you do not need to generate dependencies on files which do not exist yet.

Comment: Yes, this does it, very elegant, just a small extension to a rule. I was already starting to fiddle around with sed. Thanks a lot. Frank